# Get a selected value from radio button and insert it to MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I want to get a value from the checked radio button and insert it to MySQL.

I've already used isset(), but when i checked the result, I can't get the selected radio button.

Can someone help me?

```
<form method="post" class="input" action="doRegisCourse.php">
<table>
<?php
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
?>
<tr>
    <td><input type="radio" value="mentor" name="mentor"/></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['mentorName']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['course']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['nim']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['email']?></td>
</tr>   
<?php } ?>      
 </table>    
 <input type="submit" value="Next" name="submit">
 </form>
```

doRegisCourse.php

```
<?php
include "connect.php";
$name = $_POST['fullname'];
$name2 = $_POST['fullname2'];
$name3 = $_POST['fullname3'];
$course = $_POST['course'];
$mentor = mysql_query("SELECT * from msmentor");
$i = 1;

while ($arr = mysql_fetch_array($mentor)) {
    if (isset($_POST['mentor'])) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO membercourse(memberGroup,courseName,mentorName) 
    VALUES ('".$name."','".$course."','".$arr['mentorName']."'),('".$name2."','".$course."','".$arr['mentorName']."'),
    ('".$name3."','".$course."','".$arr['mentorName']."')";
        echo $_POST['mentor'];
     }
     $i++;
}

if (mysql_query($query)) {
    header("location:indexLogin.php");
}
```

the echo $_POST['mentor'] returns this
'mentormentormentormentor'

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) [statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: what is `echo $_POST['mentor'];` returning?

Comment: try checking the POST data..add `var_dump($_POST)` ath the start of the PHP file and see if the POST array contains `mentor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have it written currently (`<input type="radio" value="mentor" name="mentor"/>`), all of your radio buttons will have the same value: `"mentor"`. You need to set the value equal to the name of the mentor, like this:

```
<input type="radio" value="<?php echo $row['mentorName']?>" name="mentor"/>
```

Then, in `doRegisCourse.php`, you are not actually pulling the selected mentor from $_POST. You are checking to see if `$_POST['mentor']` is set, but the values for mentor that you are `INSERT`ing into `membercourse` are taken from another mysql query, not from the posted value.

That may be what you have in mind, but it seems strange to let people pick a value for mentor and then not really use it.

Comment: The same way you get it when you check if it is set: `$_POST['mentor']`. You can use that value in your query instead of `$arr['mentorName']`, if that is the value you want. I wish I could give better advice, but I'm a bit confused by what the `SELECT * from msmentor` is for, so I'm actually not completely sure what the overall goal of your code is.

Comment: Okaay.Thanks for your help! it's very helpful